# WHERE condition with Multiple LIKE referring to multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have an html/php input that gets me `$_POST['search_query']`.

I would like to filter results by post title or by tags. Whatever is simillar should appear in the results table.

I was trying this query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE activado='1' AND (titulo LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%')
                    OR (tag1 LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%') 
                    OR (tag2 LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%') 
                    OR (tag3 LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%')
```

It's filtering the "titulo" row only, I would need to fetch the simillar tags row too.

I want that the output brings any simillar Rows being fetched if the row is Titulo, Tag1, Tag2 or Tag3. At the momment is only fetching titulo rows with simillar content.

What am I missing here? 
I bet its a really simple change.

Comment: Not sure if it'll do it or not but, try putting all the like clause in single parentheses.

Comment: idk what exactly the problem is, but please try parenthesis after AND and close that parenthesis in last letter...

Comment: Try this: `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE activado='1' AND ((titulo LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%')
                    OR (tag1 LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%') 
                    OR (tag2 LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%') 
                    OR (tag3 LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%') )`

Comment: @WaqasShahid thanks for trying but its not working. i had tried it before coming here, but i did try again for respect and its not working that solution.

Comment: @WaqasShahid i had a made a bad paste with your solution. IT WORKS!
Please submit as answer. I'll be on for more time to accept as answer

Comment: I'm glad that it worked, I have posted my comment as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE activado='1'
AND ((titulo LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%')
OR (tag1 LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%')
OR (tag2 LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%')
OR (tag3 LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%') );
```

Comment: Thank you!! Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `WHERE` condition by parenthesize the conditions like below

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE activado='1' 
AND titulo LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%' 
AND ( tag1 LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%' //notice grouping here
OR    tag2 LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%'
OR    tag3 LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."%');
```

Comment: Nope. Actually its the double parenthisis as they said first.
Thanks :)